# How to schedule the data pipeline to run on first Tuesday each month and then 5 days later during night time cet using cron expression

Tags: python, sql, palantir-foundry

I wanted to create a cron job that runs on first Tuesday every month and then 5 days later of first Tuesday at Night time cet.

Answer (score 4):

Tuesday is day_of_the_week 2, and the first week is days 1-7 of the month.  Then 5 days later is a Sunday, normally day 0 (but sometimes day 7).  This will run the task at 20:00 on the local system time on those days.

```
0 20 1-7  * 2 run_some_job
0 20 6-12 * 0 run_some_job
```

Answer (score 2):

// Using the cron configs provided by @bn_ln below.

Within Foundry specifically, you'd configure this in the Schedule editor with an `OR` operator combining two `Advanced` time-based triggers like this.

[image]